# Can I use replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem with AVQueuePlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I have used `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem`: with `AVPlayer` but can it be also used with `AVQueuePlayer`?

In following apple doc, it is given that:

> This method must only be invoked on player instances created without
>   queues. If the player is initialized with multiple items the method
>   throws an exception.

What does it means? Please guide.

If it signifies that it throws exception if we use it with `AVQueuePlayer`, then I tried using it without any exception but dont know if it is right way to use.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, as per Apple docs:

> **Important**
>
> This method is not intended for use with AVQueuePlayer. If the player is initialized with multiple items this method throws an exception.

Here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1390806-replacecurrentitemwithplayeritem?language=objc